# permission error while working with logstash with filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I am working on elastic stack and i've running server of elasticsearch and logstash and for further process as described in documentaion this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/advanced-pipeline.html

And now when i am trying to execute this command:

```
sudo ./filebeat -e -c filebeat.yml -d "publish"
```

I am getting this error:

```
Exiting: error loading config file: config file ("filebeat.yml") must be owned by the beat user (uid=0) or root
```

i have changed the permissions for that file but unable to resolve this error, please help

Comment: Can you share which version of filebeat is being used and the permission of filebeat.yml by listing the filebeat configuration directory?

Comment: can you show your permissions?

Answer (score 6):

Try changing permissions with these to make sure:

```
sudo chown root ./filebeat/filebeat.yml
sudo chmod go-w ./filebeat/filebeat.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to disable strict permission checks but it is not recommended.

### Disabling Strict Permission Checks

You can disable strict permission checks from the command line by using `-strict.perms=false`, but we strongly encourage you to leave the checks enabled.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/5.3/config-file-permissions.html